# Unable to run PHPUnit outside of tests folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpunit

So I have a CodeIgniter project and I'm trying to use PHPUnit with it. My directory looks something like

```
application
node_modules
Gruntfile.js
scripts
vendor
tests
    PostTest.php
    phpunit.phar
    bootstrap.php
    phpunit.xml
composer.json
package.json
```

When I'm inside of the tests folder, I can do "phpunit ." or "php phpunit.phar ." to run the tests inside of PostTest.php and that works fine, but when I'm in the root folder, and try doing "phpunit tests", I get the error:

```
ERROR: Not Found

    The controller/method pair you requested was not found.
```

PostTest.php

```
<?php
class PostTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
      private $CI;

      public function setUp() {
          $this->CI = &get_instance();
      }

      public function testNotes() {
        $this->CI->load->model('class');
        $students = $this->CI->class->getStudents('11');
        $this->assertEquals(3, count($students->result_array()));
      }
}
```

phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <phpunit bootstrap="bootstrap.php"
             colors="true"
             convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
             convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
             convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
             processIsolation="false"
             stopOnFailure="false"
             syntaxCheck="false"
             verbose="true">
    </phpunit>
```

Does anyone have any ideas why I'm getting that error?

Answer (score 1):

Phpunit looks in the current directory for phpunit.xml, and descends into directories to find test files. So move this file to webroot and you should be sorted. Alternatively, you could specify the directory for tests to run in in the phpunit.xml and leave it where it is and add something like this (untested) to get it to include tests in webroot:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="My Test Suite">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">../</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html

Comment: So I tried moving phpunit.xml into the root before and when I did that, the error changed to `Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_instance() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/project/tests/PostTest.php on line 7` and I ran across this error before but I wasn't able to figure out a permanent solution to this.

Comment: @Jon - Just realised this is CodeIgniter and I know nothing about how CI projects are set up, so I'll butt out.